# React antd LinguiJS not working on Modal method

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, antd, linguijs

I tried to translate the title in antd `modal.confirm()` but I always receive an error `useLingui hook was used without I18nProvider`. In other pages the translation is working fine.

Here is my code:

```js
async function onLogout() {
    Modal.confirm({
        title: <Trans>Confirm Logout</Trans>,
        icon: <LogoutOutlined />,
        content: <Trans>Are you sure you want to logout?</Trans>,
        async onOk() {
            const logout = await dispatch(logoutUser())
            if (logout === "Success") {
                history.push("/login")
            }
        },
    })
}
```

Comment: did you wrapped inside I18nProvider in the app.js

Comment: yes i did wrap app.js with I18nProvider and it works fine but when i use modal.confirm() it will show an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i wrap in seperate I18nProvider for ant d modal.method context

```
   const comfirmLogoutMessage = (
    <I18nProvider i18n={i18n}>
      <Trans>Confirm Logout</Trans>
    </I18nProvider>
)
```